# Is the title of the "Vincent will Meer" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I just watched the film [Vincent will Meer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1611211/) and enjoyed it. The only thing bothering me is the title that does not seem to be grammatically correct in the absence of an article before *meer*. Is it some from of colloquialism, or is it a deliberate error in order to convey a certain meaning?

Comment: Es gibt übrigens auch einen Song in dem die Ähnlichkeit von *Meer* und *mehr* in ähnlicher Weise behandelt wird: [Der Junge mit der Gitarre - Meer seen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wR-G09rR5I)

Comment: +1 for nice film & nice question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich hoffe es ist ok wenn ich auf Deutsch antworte.

"Vincent will Meer" ("Vincent wants sea") ist eine Anspielung auf "Vinzent will mehr" (Vintent wants more"). Und das ist kein ganzer Satz, sondern der Titel eines Films, und als solcher durchaus in Ordnung. Wäre es ein ganzer Satz, dann wäre er falsch. Richtig wären beispielsweise diese Sätze:

> Vincent will zum Meer. (Vincent wants to go to the sea).
>   Vincent will das Meer haben. (Vincent wants to own the sea).

Comment: I think if Vincent doesn't want a *certain* sea, the article can be left out, like in "Ich will Freiheit!", "Sie will Milch" or "Der Dichter strebte nach Unsterblichkeit".

Comment: @Landei: Sie will Milch haben, Milch geben, Milchbubis? Immerhin kann man Milch in Portionen in Besitz nehmen, aber beim Meer wird das schwierig - in Flaschen wird es zu schnödem Salzwasser. Deswegen ist der zweite Satz auch nicht richtig und bekommt kein ^ von mir.

Comment: @userunknown Grammar doesn't always  provide for reality, even though the grammar may be functionally correct. And to express a desire doesn't necessarily mean you can actually have it. That didn't seem important to me in just having the question answered. But your point is valid.

Comment: @Kevin: Ich verstehe `provide for reality` nicht. Tut mir leid.

Comment: Die Grammatik sorgt nicht für „Wirklichkeit". :)

Comment: The title sounds odd to me. Landei is right in such way that the article can be left out, but if we talk about the sea we usually call it "das Meer", even if it is not important to see say the Atlantic: "Martin hatte noch nie in seinem Leben das Meer gesehen".

Comment: Wenn ich die See seh, brauch ich kein Meer mehr.